# How to use file contents as command-line arguments Windows

Tags: windows, file, command-line-arguments

In a Bash shell I can write

```
some_command $(< some_file)
```

to pass the contents of some_file to some_command as command-line arguments. How can I best accomplish the same thing on Windows, preferably using built-in commands/syntax?

Edit: To clarify, any form of whitespace in some_file should be treated as argument separators as is the case in my Bash example. In particular, this needs to work even if some_file has multiple lines.

Answer (score 11):

```
set /p ARGS= <some_file
some_command %ARGS%
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to make this work for files containing multiple lines?

Comment: I don't think a Windows command is allowed to contain newlines. And we say thanks by accepting the answer.

Comment: The command line in Windows can contain newlines, but getting the clunky CMD shell to handle it is probably very difficult or impossible, especially from an environment variable.

Comment: Note that `set /p` is limited to reading 1023 bytes (not characters). The byte string is decoded to UTF-16 using the console's output codepage, which defaults to the system OEM codepage. This can be changed via chcp.com, e.g. `chcp 65001` sets UTF-8 (1-4 bytes per character).